# Shell idle log out time best practice?

Tags: account-security, account-lockout

I am following CIS hardening best practices and it states that the log out time for shell is 60 seconds. This seems pretty steep for non production environments, is there any other best practise around the idle log out time?

Thanks in advance.

Chris

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PCI-DSS says the following:

> 8.1.8 If a session has been idle for more than 15 minutes, require the user to re-authenticate to re-activate the terminal or session.